# Jenkins - How to access Build number variable and use it as a Prefix/Suffix of a log name during Post build actions

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, post-build, build-numbers

I am trying to use Jenkins' Build Number in the naming of a Log that I would want to be saved as a post build action

Will the below format work

C:\Jenkins\workspace\Jmeter_Jenkins_Test_Job\Jenkins_Results\"${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"results.jtl

Answer (score 1):

As per [Building a software project](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) wiki article the environment variable you're looking for is `BUILD_NUMBER` and in case of Windows operating system you can access it as:

```
%BUILD_NUMBER%
```

so if you want to amend JMeter result file name to include build number you can do something like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/test.jmx -l /path/to/result-%BUILD_NUMBER%-.jtl
```

[image]

and in the runtime the variable will be evaluated to the current Jenkins build number:

[image]

More information just in case: [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins/)

Answer (score -1):

Without having laid my hands on a Jenkins installation for quite some time:

Yes, you can do that and it has been done before!

You could do something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
             sh 'path/to/jmeter.bat -n -t ${env.WORKSPACE}my_test.jmx -l my_test${env.BUILD_ID}_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.jtl'
        }
    }
}
```

I would propose to create the HTML dashboard report first though and then publish that in Jenkins - you could use https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/htmlpublisher/ to do that. Further you should avoid absolute paths in favor of using the `WORKSPACE` environment variable (see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables for reference). 
If you need some general idea of how to run the test via Jenkins you could have a look at https://code-maven.com/jenkins-pipeline-running-external-programs and https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui

If you already tried to achieve something and need more specific help, please come forward with some more detail.